# How to select next and previous Edit texts in a view

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have five Edit Text in my application . I also have two buttons called "Next" and "Previous". Now I want to select the next and previous edit text fields when i click the corresponding buttons form my view dynamically. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Can't you use **requestFocus()**

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the focus from one EditText to the next/previous when the corresponding button is touched?

Comment: @sandy- Thanks for the suggestion. The above is my sample application and in my real project there are nearly 50 edit text fields so doing request focus for each field is so complex. Is there any simple way to do this.

Comment: @BrianCooley - Ya i want to focus the next/previous EditText when the corresponding button is selected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = getCurrentFocus().getNextFocusDownId();
        if(id != View.NO_ID) {
            findViewById(id).requestFocus();
            System.out.println("Next");
        }
    }
});

btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = getCurrentFocus().getNextFocusUpId();
        if(id != View.NO_ID) {
            findViewById(id).requestFocus();
            System.out.println("Back");
        }
    }
});
```

This is the XML where you have to set the focus order

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et2"
    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/et2"
    ....../>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et2"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et1"
    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/et1"
    ...../>
```

**Edit**

If you are creating view dynamic then you should use below methods to set the next focus

```
setNextFocusDownId(id)
setNextFocusUpId(id);
```

Comment: i can use this in an XLM code but I m creating edit text at run time so i cant do this. Any suggestion.

Comment: You should accept proper answer so that other user can also get the benefit.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of

```
android:nextFocusLeft

android:nextFocusRight

android:nextFocusUp

android:nextFocusDown
```

in your editText's attributes in your layout.xml.

e.g. `android:nextFocusDown="@id/myNextEditText"`

For more details about how to use it please follow [this link.](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-the-basics-of-control-focus-order/)

Comment: How can i use this in my button click event.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, I've given link to follow.
Or if you are generating your views dynamically, i.e. through .java files, then you can refer to my second answer.

Answer (score 3):

i think this may help you,

http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/changing-button-text-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_next :
            if(editText1.hasFocus()){
                editText2.requestFocus();
            }else if(editText2.hasFocus()){
                editText3.requestFocus();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btn_previous :
            if(editText2.hasFocus()){
                editText1.requestFocus();
            }else if(editText3.hasFocus()){
                editText2.requestFocus();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong syntax (editText1!.hasFocus()) it should be (!editText1.hasFocus()).This will not helped. according to your logic it will only focus edittext1 and edittext2

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. That was absolutely a typo (and copy paste). That is an syntax error actually. Edited.